# Using others answer as an edit in my answer

Tags: discussion, edits, answers, duplicate-answers

Related question: [Oracle SQL - Get records with latest date on non-unique data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46440688/4519059)
In this question [dbajtr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8086878/dbajtr) posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46440895/4519059) before me that was wrong - as mentioned by OP in comments -, After that I posted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46441062/4519059), Then [dbajtr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8086878/dbajtr) after finding that his answer is wrong edit his post by adding an answer similar to - I can say as same as - mine after 7 minutes of my answer posted, and so on...

I think when OP started the communication with [dbajtr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8086878/dbajtr), OP doesn't check other answers, So, I can think about this as a way to get my answer accepted by OP - by communicating/commenting - Can it be fine? Or I should do some other actions?

Comment: Considering there is another answer there with basically the same code it looks like this is just one of those things where your going to get the same answer.  I don't anything bad is happening here.  All of the answers though a low quality as none of them actually explain how they work.